# NPE when loading resource from directory outside of classpath

Tags: java, css, javafx, classpath

I'm using JavaFX and attempting to load a CSS file into my scene.

```
scene.getStyleSheets().add(Main.class.getResource("res/application.css").toExternalForm();
```

Throws a NPE. I'm thinking it's because the css file is not inside the classpath, but I'm not sure how to load it this way. I don't want to include the css file in my package directory (com.somecompany.package), I'd much rather include it in a separate directory that can be deployed on it's own (so user can modify if desired).

How can I load a css file (or resource for that matter) from outside the classpath?

My stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.somecompany.someapp.Main.start(Main.java:30)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$5.run(LauncherImpl.java:319)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$5.run(PlatformImpl.java:206)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl$4.run(PlatformImpl.java:173)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.access$100(WinApplication.java:29)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$3$1.run(WinApplication.java:73)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: If it is unable to find the file then it should throw FileNotFoundException... can you paste the stacktrace of NPE?

Comment: @GV `Class#getResource()` returns `null` if it does not find the resource.

Comment: added stack trace. line 30 of Main.class is the line above. @SotiriosDelimanolis is right, it's a npe because it can't find it. I'm not sure how to make it find it though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a `/` at the beginning of the `String` argument to search for the resource at the root of the classpath

```
scene.getStyleSheets().add(Main.class.getResource("/res/application.css").toExternalForm();
```

Otherwise the path is resolved relative to the package that `Main` is in. The rules for resolving a resource are [explained in the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

This is not ideal if you want to actually modify the file. In that case you should get the file from the file system.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/path/to/file");     
scene.getStyleSheets().add(path.toUri().toURL()).toExternalForm();
```

Comment: can you elaborate on why it's not ideal to load directly (example 1) if I plan to make it user editable (comparing to example 2)?

Comment: @SnakeDoc First, you can't get an `OutputStream` from a `URL` (you can get the path and use `File` or `Path`, but meh). Second, what happens if you run your application from a `jar`?

Comment: hmm, interesting points. I do plan to package the program in a jar. I will give your second example a try

Comment: @SnakeDoc In the second example, the file is not meant to be in the `jar`.

Comment: right, the `res` directory will be outside the jar, jar containing only class files, res containing css and images, etc. I think this will still work then?

Comment: @snakeDoc Yeah, just give an absolute path.